# Accessory Action section not being shown when drag a segue into Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to associate a segue with a button to show a `Navigation Controller` but when I drag from the button to the `Navigation Controller` only `Action Segue` section is being shown, but not `Accessory Action` section.

I know that in other projects I was able to do the same and select `Show` segue option but in this project I am not able to do that.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

How can I make that the segue allows me to select `Show` option?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution so I post it here because it can be helpful for someone.

If you want to be able to access to `Accesory Action` segue section you will have to do:

- Select your `View Controller`.
- Go to the `File inspector` on the right panel of XCode.
- Activate `Use Auto Layout` and `Use Size Classes` options.

Now you can drag from your `button` (or whatever) to your `Navigation Controller` and you will see your `Accesory Action` (with `Show` option) section.

[image]